# Compare data in large excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, validation, large-files

I have two large (very large) excel spreadsheets, and I need to find the differences between the two. They are both outputs of SQL queries, one with old code and one with new code and I need to validate that the new code still returns all the same stuff as the old code. What I'm mostly interested in is knowing which row or column is different in the new version, and not as much about how they are different.

The spreadsheets are too large for excel to handle. I've also tried the ExcelCompare project from na-ka-na on github, but I ran into memory issues with that as well. Is there a (free) tool that can handle these big tables, or a technique I could use to break them up into more manageable pieces?

Comment: you can use a java program to get the xls file in input so you can read eqch line (cln1, cln2) test if the 2 values mach

Comment: If you can save both as a CSV, do so and try comparing in WinMerge. If it's too large, break it down and compare some more. Otherwise, I'll go with Python and compare this in Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not keep it in SQL and write some simple [set operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)) -- such as `intersect`?

Or you could use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and the [`dplyr`](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package and use `setdiff(dataset1, dataset1)`